# NoSuchMethodError when trying to convert Object List to String List

Tags: java, json, list

I'm working on some other guys code and he tries to read data from a JSON config file. It always worked, but I'm suddenly getting a NoSuchMethodError.

This is the part that's causing the problem:

```
config_bcs_filterstatuscodes = new LinkedList<>();
        for (Object filtercode : appconfig.getJSONObject("projektron_bcs").getJSONArray("filter_statuscodes").toList()) {
            config_bcs_filterstatuscodes.addLast(filtercode.toString());
        }
```

The code tries to convert a List of Objects to a List of Strings.

The error I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json.JSONArray.toList()Ljava/util/List;
at middleware.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

I have no idea why it suddenly tells me that there is no such method, because it always worked until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSONArray from "org.json" doesn't have a toList() method
You should iterate directly the JSONArray object like this:

```
for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){   
   config_bcs_filterstatuscodes.add(jsonArray.getString(i));  
}
```